# CommandNotFoundException: get-windowsoptionalfeature

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell Version 2 on windows 7. I need to run the following command: `get-windowsoptionalfeature`

but when I run: `get-command -Verb Get`, the `get-windowsoptionalfeature` is not listed and as a result when I enter the command I receive an error stating that "get-windowsoptionalfeature" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function.

Am I missing a dll or something?

Answer (score 2):

`get-windowsoptionalfeature` is only [applicable to Windows 8 & Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852173.aspx).

Comment: Hi thanx is there a similar command I can use for windows 7 then? Or is it not possible?

Comment: I tried get-windowsfeature but I still get the error as stated in the question.

Comment: There is simply nothing equivalent built into Windows 7.

Comment: Ok thanx so much for your help! appreciated. I will try mjolinor's answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this in powershell console

```
PS C:\>$feature=Get-WmiObject -query "select * from  Win32_OptionalFeature"
```

Now $feature is array of object of type ManagementObject.

to prove it try

```
PS C:\> $feature[0]
```

this is what I get.

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_OptionalFeature
__SUPERCLASS     : CIM_LogicalElement
__DYNASTY        : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH        : Win32_OptionalFeature.Name="OEMHelpCustomization"
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 6
__DERIVATION     : {CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER         : TTL001343
__NAMESPACE      : root\cimv2
__PATH           : \\TTL001343\root\cimv2:Win32_OptionalFeature.Name="OEMHelpCustomization"
Caption          :
Description      :
InstallDate      :
InstallState     : 2
Name             : OEMHelpCustomization
Status           :
```

You can get query specific objects as well.
example:

```
PS C:\>$feature=Get-WmiObject -query "select * from  Win32_OptionalFeature where name = 'RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell'"
```

Now this will be single object not an array.

Answer (score 0):

There's the Client Manager Module:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSClientManager