# Disable Powershell 2.0 under Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows, powershell, security, windows-7

I just installed WMF 5.1 on a Windows 7 Enterprise Workstation in order to benefit from the security features and Windows Powershell 5.1 that come along with it.

Now I want to disable powershell 2.0 to prevent compromising those security features.

Is there any way to do this, like "Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2" under Windows 10 does?

Thanks in advance and greetings

Marvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
It does not appear to be possible to only disable the v2 in Windows 7.
Windows 7 comes per default with v2, so it is baked in and not a feature the way it is in Windows 8 and Windows 10.

My guess as to why you cannot find any way to do it for Windows 7 is that [Mainstream support for Windows 7 ended back in 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet) and the extended support ends in 1½ year in 2020. So it looks like Microsoft doesn't bother with working around this issue in Windows 7 and basically wants people to upgrade if they need this functionally disabled for security reasons.

**For Windows 8 and 10**

If you have PowerShell 5.1 installed, you should be able to just use the `WindowsOptionalFeature` cmdlets to do this on Windows 10.

To check for the feature you can do:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object {$_.FeatureName -like "PowerShellV2"}
```

Then to Disable:

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root"
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2"
```

Before you do this however I would recommend that you read the [blogpost from Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/08/24/windows-powershell-2-0-deprecation/) about the deprecation to make sure there is nothing on the system that uses Powershell 2.0

You could also use the GUI to turn it off in Windows 8:

1. Go to the Control Panel and select the **Programs and Features** option.
2. Next click on the **Turn Windows features on or off** link on the left panel.
3. When the Windows Features dialog appears, scroll down to **Windows PowerShell V2** and *uncheck* the feature to disable it or check to enable.

[Petri article about uninstalling/downgrading Powershell](https://www.petri.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-powershell)

Comment: That was my first try. Unfortunately I have neither `WindowsOptionalFeature` nor the Option in the OptionalFeatures GUI...

Comment: P.S. I also tried the options given in [CommandNotFoundException: get-windowsoptionalfeature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017436/commandnotfoundexception-get-windowsoptionalfeature) but **Windows PowerShell V2** is not listed....

Comment: You are entirely right, I didn't have a Win 7 machine to test on.
After checking a few sources it appears that there is not any supported ways from Microsofts side to do this on Win 7. I have updated my answer.